# need 2 int generators not generating same int

Tags: java, random

How would i make the 2 random int generators not generating the same integer? My sample class is below, assuming the program runs. Thank you for your help.

```
public class TestRandom{
    int num; 

    public TestRandom(){
        num = 0;
    }
    public TestRandom(int x){
        num = x;
    }
    public String toString(){
        String print;
        if (num == 1)
            print = "1";
        else if(num == 2)
            print = "2";
        else
            print = "---";
        return print;
    }
}

public class Test{
    TestRandom[] s= new TestRandom[20];
    Random ran = new Random();
    public void setArray(){
        for(int i=0; i<s.length; i++)
            s[i] = new TestRandom();

        for(int k=0; k<4; k++)
            int RandomNum = ran.nextInt(s.length);
        s[RandomNum] = new TestRandom(1);

        for(int e=0; e<4; e++)
            int RandomNum = ran.nextInt(s.length);
        s.[RandomNum] = new TestRandom(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I fixed a bit of you formatting. Please consider doing something like that in the future. It makes it a lot easier for us to grok your code.

Comment: thank you for helping me with the formatting. I will keep it in mind for future references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you make two generators not generate the same number it's not random.
2. If you anyway want that functionality use a single instance and if the second number generated is the same as the previous one generate another number.

Note that randomness and uniqueness doesn't really go together.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import java.util.Random;    
public class TestRandom{
     int num=0; 
     int num2=0;
     Random ran = new Random();
     num = ran.nextInt();
     num2 = ran.nextInt();
     System.out.print(num+" "+num2);
}
```

Comment: How does that code enforce *"not generating the same integer"*?

Comment: it may generate same integer. i just give an idea and let Phong think how to make the integer not same

Comment: On the sliding scale of 'comment or answer' I think this better fits 'comment' since it fails to address an important part of the OPs question.  Of course, you don't have enough rep. yet to comment, but be patient.

Answer (score 0):

Add each generated int to a set.

Check each int generated to see if the int exists in the set.

If yes, generate a new int.

e.g.

```
public class Test{
    TestRandom[] s= new TestRandom[20];
    Random ran = new Random();
  public void setArray(){
    for(int i=0; i<s.length; i++)
      s[i] = new TestRandom();

    HashSet<Integer> usedInts = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for(int k=0; k<4; k++) {
      int RandomNum;
      do {
        RandomNum = ran.nextInt(s.length);
      } while (!usedInts.add(RandomNum)); // loop until RandomNum not duplicated
      s[RandomNum] = new TestRandom(1);
    }
    for(int e=0; e<4; e++) {
      int RandomNum;
      do {
        RandomNum = ran.nextInt(s.length);
      } while (!usedInts.add(RandomNum)); // loop until RandomNum not duplicated
      s.[RandomNum] = new TestRandom(2);
    }
  }
```

Comment: even though this is be on my programming skill, thank you for the answer. User217